# Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I already have Composer version @ package_branch_alias_version @ (1.0.0-beta2) and Laravel Installer 2.1.0. but when I want to make a laravel project, it displays an error like this :

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[5.1.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0 requires ext-filter ^7.1 -> the requested PHP extension filter has the wrong version (7.2.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) installed.
  Problem 2
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0 requires ext-filter ^7.1 -> the requested PHP extension filter has the wrong version (7.2.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) installed.
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.10.3 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ^2.0|^3.0.2|^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[5.1.0].
    - Installation request for phpspec/prophecy v1.10.3 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.10.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

What should I do? I have searched for a solution on the internet, but did not find the same.

Comment: Solved, guys. I uninstalled composer 1.0.0 and installed composer 1.10.0

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP 7.1 if you want to use those packages. Keep in mind that you should upgrade to php 7.3 at least.

Answer (score -1):

As per `phpdocumentor` documentation. It require atleast `PHP 7.2`. To resolve this either `upgrade your PHP version` or `downgrade phpdocumentor package`

```
requires

php: ^7.2
phpdocumentor/type-resolver: ^1.0
webmozart/assert: ^1
phpdocumentor/reflection-common: ^2.0
ext-filter: ^7.1
```

https://packagist.org/packages/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock#5.1.0

Comment: @Stev try to use `PHP 7.1`